# How to create a new cell when I click the textbox which is already in uitableviewcell in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am trying to create an address book in the iPhone, similar to the iPhone Address Book. When I want to create a new contact, while entering the value in `UITextField` to enter the phone number, it is creating a new cell in the `TableView`. I have tried the code below, but it is creating multiple cells.

```
(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
 UITableViewCell *parentCell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tview indexPathsForSelectedRows];        NSIndexPath *currRow = [self.tview indexPathForCell:parentCell];

[self addRow:currRow text:textField.text];    

}


(void)addRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath text:(NSString *)text
{
  NSIndexPath *nextRow;

    if(indexPath.section==0)
       i++;
    nextRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i-1 inSection:indexPath.section];

        [self.tview beginUpdates];
        //    [self.tview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tview insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tview endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: You must be saving the entries form the text field into a MutableArray and giving the number of cells for section as [array count].In the function where you are resigning FirstResponder just reload the table and as your array count is increased your cell count will aslo increase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in your code [self.tview indexPathsForSelectedRows];  
does not return the selected cell while it returns the array of index path ... that's why its creating a multiple row
```

make a custome UITextViewClass and have one property with NSIndexPath;
and assign it in cell for row at index path ...

```
yourTextView.yourIndexPath = indexPath;

//the try to use this method

(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self addRow:indexPath text:textField.text];
}

// then add your row as you want....
```

Hope this will help you